# How to create a table in wpf dinamically (from code) in which each table cell is a textBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

as the title says I want to create a table in which each table cell is a textBox. Then I want to save the value of those textboxes in a file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what will be the data source for your table and how the table should look like, but let's say that you have a window in which you have Grid named MyGrid

You can dynamically add rows and columns and make table

```
    public void MakeTable(int columns, int rows)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
            MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
            r.Height = GridLength.Auto;
            MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();                 
                tb.Text = "my text for " + x + " " + y;
                Grid.SetColumn(tb, x);
                Grid.SetRow(tb, y);
                MyGrid.Children.Add(tb);
            }
        }
    }

    public string TableValue(int column, int row, int rows)
    {
        int i = row + column * rows;
        return ((TextBox)MyGrid.Children[i]).Text;
    }
```

Function call can than looks like this:

```
        int columns = 2;
        int rows = 3;

        MakeTable(columns, rows); //prepare table

        string s = TableValue(0, 2, rows);  //read string from coordinates
```

To save data for example into a text file you have to define some rules. For example, on top of the file write the number of columns and rows, and then individual cells. To understand the content while reloading. Or place tabulator between columns...

Comment: Works perfect!! Thank you very much!